# Cache Issue on mobile and desktop

Tags: magento2, css, cache, html, mobile

facing the cache issue.

Cache Clean issue - HTML/CSS changes are not reflected on normal browsers. It shows in private or Incognito window. We can't tell each customer to open the website in Incognito window.

Is there any method to solve this issue. We are facing this issue. Please let me know if any solution.

Comment: Why don't you use cache headers?

Answer (score 4):

for the HTML, JS and CSS changes you can enable the merging and bundling the JS and CSS files, and then it will merge it to the client's browser too and reflect the changes, 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/js-bundling.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/performance-best-practices/advanced-js-bundling.html

Another option is to enable the versioning and run deploy.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a tool like cloudflare to manage your cache. Now, your changes will never change for every browser immediately. That's just not how the internet works. If the changes are how you want it on a refreshed browser, the changes will get to all your users pretty quickly. Using something like cloudflare will give you more control over this process.